# Volley Request Inside a Service

Tags: android, android-service

What i want is to request a server using volley inside a service continuously, When a new entry is added in a database it notify a user that a new entry is available. I used volley to request a server and when a new request is added in a database it notify in a notification bar.

Comment: use firebase don't waste android resources

Comment: how to implement a volley request inside service

Comment: volley works inside service what's the problem? edit the question and specify it

Comment: how can i implement this

Comment: is there any tutorial or llink?

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb

Comment: use Firebase real time database....

Comment: Time to hire a slave to write that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should add it to your build.gradle file in your project.

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'}
```

To make a request using Volley you should create a RequestQueue and pass it Request objects. The RequestQueue will manage the threads for the network, parsing, reading and writing operations. Below a quick code I did to make a request using the Volley lib.

```
private void consultarObjJson() {
    RequestQueue pilha = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url=webserviceCaminho+"alunos";
    StringRequest consultaString = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String resposta) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Resposta" + resposta);
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson mGson = builder.create();
            List<AlunoObj> post = new ArrayList<AlunoObj>();
            post = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(resposta, AlunoObj[].class));
            alunoAdapter = new AlunoAdapter(getBaseContext(), post, "MainActivity");
            recyclerView.setAdapter(alunoAdapter);
            alunoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError erro) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Erro :" + erro.getMessage());
        }
    }); pilha.add(consultaString);
    }
```

For more details about how to use it check here [Volley - Android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)